# When I run R in parallels for OSX, how do I run system()? What path should I be using?

Tags: r, system, parallels

When running R in Parallels for OSX, how does one run system() commands?  For example, a simple system("dir") returns a 127.  What path should I use?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `system("ls")` instead of `system("dir")` in mac os?

Comment: If you want to use `dir`, then you should probably install bootcamp and Windows, and boot that instead of OSX.

Comment: What operating system are you running inside Parallels?

Comment: @MarcB What? why would it be preferred to require rebooting to use Windows when it would work _just fine_ in a VM?

Comment: @hrbrmstr: try running a win7 vm inside a 4gig mac... gets rather painful unless you've upgraded the host memory.

Comment: @marcb Why are you assuming the OP is running with such constraints?

Comment: I am running windows 7 in parallels on OSX.  Memory is not an issue though.